# Improving sub select query on two tables without relationship

Tags: sql

I am trying to return the count of employees by salary band and can return data using the following sql but wondered if this was the most efficient way of achieving it?

I know creating a join between the tables would be better but that is not possible in this instance.

```
select *, (select count(*) from EmployeeSalary where salary between minsalary and maxsalary) from SalaryBands
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It's odd you say it is not possible, because it is possible, right?

```
select ID, Name, MinSalary, MaxSalary, count(Salary) as SalaryCount
from SalaryBands
left outer join EmployeeSalary on salary between minsalary and maxsalary
group by ID, Name, MinSalary, MaxSalary
```

Now, I am not sure I would actually use that... I would actually go with your query, but transformed to be more readable...

```
select ID,
       Name,
       MinSalary,
       MaxSalary,
       (select count(*)
        from EmployeeSalary
        where salary between minsalary and maxsalary
       ) as BandCount
from SalaryBands
```

Comment: fixed `*` -> `Salary`

Comment: thanks for your reply - what I meant was that I can't create a foreign key column :)